# Is it possible to skip ads from twitch with Python using streamlink & ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, twitch, streamlink

I have the following code that pulls 60 seconds from the ESLCSGO twitch stream and downloads it to "output.mp4":

```
import streamlink, subprocess

streams = streamlink.streams("twitch.tv/ESL_CSGO")

audio = streams["best"]

subprocess.call("ffmpeg -i " + str(audio.url) + " -t 60 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4 -y")
```

I've noticed that if I manually clip on the .m3u8 generated by streamlink.streams() I don't get any ads, but once ffmpeg converts it to an .mp4 there's ads. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: @Lunatech nope, I still haven't been able to circumvent it